# ..... beneficial vitamins may be, they mustn't be taken excessively

Tags: inversion

What is the right answer ?

I think it is kind of reversion but I cannot figure out which one is.

> ..... beneficial vitamins may be, they mustn't be taken excessively.
>
> A) How
>
> B) Despite
>
> C) However
>
> D) Though

Answer (score 2):

Multiple choice format is a little weird here.  Here are the possible correct options.

- Despite how beneficial vitamins may be...
- However beneficial vitamins may be...
- Though vitamins may be beneficial...

So of your options, only C works.  But just saying A, B, and D are wrong would be misleading.   Note the change of order on D.  "Though beneficial vitamins may be..." only works if you want to sound like Yoda.

Comment: +1 for "saying A, B, and D are wrong would be misleading". Although I don't really like the ***despite*** version, for example, [the usage does occur](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22despite+how+cold+it+was%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (personally I'd either rephrase completely or go for ***in spite of***).